# es6 template string + short object literal transpilation failed [gulp, babel]

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've got an extremely small ES6 code:

```
var name = "MyName";
var version = "1.2.3";

var theThing = {
  name,
  version,
  run: () => {
    console.log(`You're using ${this.name}@${this.version}`);
  }
};

theThing.run();
```

When I run it inside the browser console (chrome 53), I get the expected result: `You're using MyName@1.2.3` is logged to the console. Both template strings work along with shortened object literal syntax.

However, when I try to use gulp/babel to transpile this code down to ES5, using the most basic setup (taken from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)):

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I get following output:

```
"use strict";

var name = "MyName";
var version = "1.2.3";

var theThing = {
  name: name,
  version: version,
  run: function run() {
    console.log("You're using " + undefined.name + "@" + undefined.version);
  }
};

theThing.run();
```

As you can see, it's calling `undefined.name` instead of `this.name`, I've got absolutely no idea why is `this` replaced with `undefined`. Of course, this code doesn't work as expected:

```
VM329:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…)
```

and is **not** ES6 compliant (original implementation of ES6 in chrome53 works correctly).

You can also see this issue in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=var%20name%20%3D%20%22MyName%22%3B%0D%0Avar%20version%20%3D%20%221.2.3%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20theThing%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%2C%0D%0A%20%20version%2C%0D%0A%20%20run%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60You're%20using%20%24%7Bthis.name%7D%40%24%7Bthis.version%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AtheThing.run()%3B).

Am I doing something wrong - or is it a bug in babel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer consists of 2 points:

- arrow functions and classical ES5 functions have completely different `this` binding. `this` in classical functions is very dynamic (determined in runtime, no matter where is it defined), whereas in arrows, it's lexically bound (bound in where it's placed, runtime has no affect on that, runtime is already too late to change it). Lexical scope makes an arrow function *borrow* `this` from the closest enclosing classical function, if present. If not present, it's taken from global scope...
- if not in strict mode, `window` is taken. If in strict mode, `undefined` is taken

... which precisely answers above question.

Answer (score 2):

in your original source try to replace

```
var theThing = {
  name,
  version,
  run: () => {
    console.log(`You're using ${this.name}@${this.version}`);
  }
};
```

by

```
var theThing = {
  name,
  version,
  run: function () {
    console.log(`You're using ${this.name}@${this.version}`);
  }
};
```

The arrow syntax function changes the way `this` works

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions don't bind to `this` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). Therefore when you define the function, the object doesn't yet exist... so Babel doesn't know about the context.

Getting rid of the arrow function will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow function `this` points to `window` because of the lexical binding. When you call `theThing.run()`, you actually get  `window.name`, and `window.version` in the template. If you rename the the global variables it won't work:

```js
var n = "MyName";
var v = "1.2.3";

var theThing = {
  name: n,
  version: v,
  run: () => {
    console.log(`You're using ${this.name}@${this.version}`);
  }
};

theThing.run();
```

To solve that, don't use the arrow function:

```js
    var n = "MyName";
    var v = "1.2.3";

    var theThing = {
      name: n,
      version: v,
      run() {
        console.log(`You're using ${this.name}@${this.version}`);
      }
    };

    theThing.run();
```